# Twilio SMS - Unable to verify called ID in Twilio dashboard

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twiliosms

I was trying to add new verified caller IDs for a Twilio trial account, the first times I added verified caller IDs everything worked fine, but from a couple of days ago, whenever I try to verify a new caller ID I receive this message: "We were unable to verify your Caller ID".

I tried verifying numbers from USA and some from LATAM, but it does not matter how many times I try, I always get the same message. I also checked my geo permissions, and I renabled the +1 for US and Canada numbers and +505 for Nicaraguan numbers which are the regions for the numbers I am trying to verify.

Does someone knows or have an idea of why this might be happening?

Comment: did you find any solution? same problem here...

Comment: It seems is a internal bug! I talked to twilio support and they helped me adding the phone numbers manually! Not really sure if its already working at this date